# Error PLS-00103?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am writing some PL/SQL code which inserts a new record into the database. The procedure needs to check for reasonable inputs and place a new record in two tables.

The code I have so far does not work - I keep getting error PLS-00103. I have looked at other threads and it suggests there is a missing or misplaced '/' but I cannot see where that might be.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_book(
    b_isbn IN books.isbn%type,
    b_title IN books.title%type,
    b_summary IN books.summary%type,
    b_author IN books.author%type,
    b_datepub IN books.date_published%type,
    b_pagecount IN books.page_count%type)
AS
BEGIN
    IF b_isbn is NULL
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Enter a valid ISBN');
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO books (isbn, title, summary, author, date_published, page_count)
    VALUES (b_isbn, b_title, b_summary, b_author, bdatepub, b_pagecount);
END add_book;
/

BEGIN
    add_book ('b_isbn','b_title','b_summary','b_datepub','b_pagecount');
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_bookcopies(
    bc_barcode IN book_copies.barcode_id%type,
    bc_isbn IN book_copies.isbn%type)
AS
BEGIN
    IF bc_isbn is NULL
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Enter a valid ISBN');
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO book_copies (barcode_ID, isbn)
    VALUES (bc_barcode, bc_isbn);
END add_bookcopies;
/

BEGIN
    add_bookcopies(abc_barcode, 'abc_isbn');
END;
```

Comment: You have two procedures and two anonymous blocks. Which of the four throws the error? Also: the error message has more detail than just an error code; always post it in full.

Comment: It also depends on where/how you created the procedures.  Are they in a package or standalone?  I assume a package because there are two procedures in the code above.  Having said that, everything after the second "/"' in the code will cause an error, delete the first "/" and all the code after the second "/".  You only need the one "/" to end the package body.  Oh, I forgot about the other anonymous block, delete that as well.

If standalone, delete the first "/", the "/" indicates the end of the entire code block.

This all ssumes that you're using Sql*Plus or something similar.

Comment: Displaying` 'Enter a valid ISBN'` won't prevent the INSERT from running. If you have a NOT NULL constraint on the column then the insert will fail, but a DBMS_OUTPUT call is not "validation" in any meaningful sense.